# Python ImportError - cannot import name

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and i cant to resolve one error.
So i have two folders "Common" and "Parsers". In "Common"-folder there is a file - FileUtils.py:

```
import re

def get_filename(target):
    pattern = "^.*\/(.*)$"

    names = re.findall(pattern, target)

    return names[0]
```

In "Parsers"-folder there is also one file - Parser.py:

```
import os
import urllib
import urllib.request
import re
from Common import FileUtils

#urls - list of strings
def parse_images(urls)
    ...
    ...
    full_path = os.path.join(directory, FileUtils.get_filename(final_link))
    ...
```

And finally in root folder - Main.py:

```
from Parsers import Parser

def main():
    url = ['http://www.example.com']
    Parser.parse_images(url)
```

At first line of Main.py - "from Parsers import Parser" PyCharm throws an error - "ImportError: cannot import name 'Parser'".

Can someone explain me what i'm doing wrong? Thanks.

P.S. When all code in one file - program works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set up your folders as Python packages? If you wish to import from a directory then you'll need a `__init__.py` file inside to do so (an empty one will work).

Try creating an empty `Parsers/__init__.py` file and see if that fixes it

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have created a simple folders, rather than Python packages. After I put the code in Python packages my app  working fine.